# Wcf. Rest. Architecture. Need advice

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, architecture

Suppose I have this simple contract which I've taken from MS examples and altered a bit:

```
  [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
        public interface IService
        {
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml),
             Description(
                 "Adds a customer to customers collection. The response Location header contains a URL to the added item.")]
            [OperationContract]
            Customer AddCustomer(Customer customer);

            [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "{id}"),
             Description(
                 "Deletes the specified customer from customers collection. Returns NotFound if there is no such customer.")
            ]
            [OperationContract]
            void DeleteCustomer(string id);

            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}"),
             Description(
                 "Returns the specified customer from customers collection. Returns NotFo`enter code here`und if there is no such customer.")
            ]
            [OperationContract]
            Customer GetCustomer(string id);

            [WebGet(UriTemplate = ""), Description("Returns all the customers in the customers collection.")]
            [OperationContract]
            List<Customer> GetCustomers();

            [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "{id}"),
             Description("Updates the specified customer. Returns NotFound if there is no such customer.")]
            [OperationContract]
            Customer UpdateCustomer(string id, Customer newCustomer);
        }
```

I need this contract to expose over webhttp REST and over nettcp binding (with sessions).

My case(contract) is much harder, so I need to understand whether to have one implementation for both purposes and differentiate somehow between webhttpbinding call or nettcpbinding call  or  provide different realizations for each endpoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the question I would ask myself is what does having a service contract like you describe get me in terms of development ease and future maintenance. My instinct is to follow the single responsibility principle and have separate service contracts and endpoints over a common code base.

Comment: Well, first of all thank you for reply. I asked if there is common practice about it, maybe someone else had similiar problems(questions) and their following decisions about that.

Comment: Mostly code will do CRUD operations, but does it have sense to write smth like: if(nettcp){do this} else{do that}. As for me I suppose that it is better to have two implementations.

Comment: I agree because when it comes right down to it, you would be mixing two different architectural styles: soap/rpc-oriented and http/document-oriented. That's one reason I believe Microsoft moved the new HTTP-based API from the WCF team to the ASP.NET team.

Comment: Why you need both nettcp and webhttp? Why you need session? As example you can have only one REST endpoint statless. In most cases session is used for authorization. Use REST techniques for authorization, Authorization header.

Comment: For example, if I need to have stateful sessions for desktop UI  and statless session for web clients.So for now I undestand that I should two separete implementations, even maybe two different interefaces -- not like above.

Comment: In my understanding of REST you should *not* have state anywhere but in the requests themselves. And you should utilize the http protocol why using nettcp seems impossible.

Comment: You can work with stateless REST service but emulate your session. For example, it's common to pass user authentication result token in special 'Authentication' HTTP header. Such header is passed with each request and actually emulates session with authorized user. So, when session is only one reason for two endpoints, than this problem could be resolved with only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need to mix different architectural styles - SOAP/WS-* (nettcpbinding) and REST. With correct implementation they have differences. And when you will be mixing such styles in one service, logic for your services methods will contain definitely multiple if-than or switch cases to determine in which mode you are working, also that could be problems when working both with HTTP or WCF contexts.

I suggest you to create to separate endpoints(contract) - one for REST and one for WS-*/SOAP and follow their architectural styles.

To share logic between them, encapsulate your business logic in separate layer (classes) and then you can simply reuse it without mixing REST or WS-* specific logic and your business logic.

When dealing with simple CRUD operations, consider to use WCF Data Serivces, that could generate REST/OData endpoints for you based on database.

UPD from comment:
You can work with stateless REST service but "emulate" your session. As example, it's common to pass user authentication result token in special 'Authentication' HTTP header in each request to recognize and differ users. Such header is passed with each request and actually emulates session with authorized user. So, when session is only one reason for two endpoints, than this problem could be resolved with only one of them.